# Скрытие номера карты

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как скрыть номер банковской карты (16 знаков)?

На входе лог (txt файл), в котором местами имеются полные номера карт. Их нужно привести от вида:

```
1234123412341234
```

к виду:

```
1234 **** **** 1234
```

P.S. Чтение/запись в файл реализованы.

Comment: Ну а что у вас номер карты? **Любые** ровно 16 цифр подряд или нет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример кода:

```
from re import sub

# Открываю файл для чтения и читаю содержимое в переменную

file = open("ваш_файл", 'r')
text = ''.join(file.readlines())

# Применяю замену по регулярному выражению

new_text = sub(r'(\d{4})\d{8}(\d{4})', r'\1 **** **** \2', text)

# Открываю файл на запись и записываю изменённый текст

file = open("ваш_файл", 'w')

file.write(new_text)
file.close()
```

NB: Данный код меняет любую последовательность из идущих подряд 16 цифр. Он никак не учитывает, что может встретиться число, не являющееся номером карт, или номером, записанным в другом формате.

Comment: 1- используйте `text = file.read()` вместо `text = ''.join(file.readlines())` (или лучше [`for line in file` (c `fileinput`)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17140886/4279)) 2- `re.sub()` обычно легче читать чем `sub()`. Первое явно указывает, что используется стандартная функция. Во втором случае приходится искать где имя определено. (то есть используйте просто `import re`) 3- используйте `with open(filename) as file:` вместо `file = open(filename)` чтобы файл автоматически закрывался по выходу из `with`-блока без явного `file.close()`.